# How to retrieve data from remote server wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with my wordpress site when I access data(json) from a remote server.

I have to access data and show it in a wordpress page. I am developing a shortcode plugin for it. The problem is if the data is small the data is retrieved and if its size is huge the operation fails. After hours of Googling I found that I have to increase the php memory limit and maximum execution time through .htaccess, which I have done and the result is same.

I have used

`wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url,$args))` and CURL for retrieving data but no hope.
Now I am using `file_gets_contents()`

Please suggest me a solution.

Thank you

Comment: Did you verify that setting `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` actually works? (try `phpinfo()` to find out the current settings)
Often the configuration through `.htaccess` is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The site is in wordpress. The max_execution_time is 3000 and memory_limit is 76M, I have verified it through phpinfo()